# Which server-side .NET technology to use with Sencha Touch

Tags: .net, architecture, sencha-touch-2

I am wondering which .NET server technology is advisable to use as a back-end for a rich mobile application project intended to be written in Sencha Touch?

The back-end should be responsible for providing data for the mobile app, collecting user input, authentication, maintaining session state, communication with the server database and eventually doing some business logic where it makes sense. As an object-relational mapper we are currently using a custom framework.

If more platforms come into your mind (I've stumbled upon WCF+REST with JSON, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web API...), what are their respective advantages and disadvantages? Which of them "match" best the underlying paradigms in Sencha Touch? What about their unit-testability, maintainability and future perspective?

Comment: I like using HttpHandlers to communicate between front and backend

Comment: @Simon: Your link answers a question concerning applications using AJAX and JSON data in general; my question targets specifically Sencha Touch - which is indeed based on these technologies but maybe there are some other issues to consider...

Comment: I think it's duplicated because sencha is totally agnostic regarding the server (it works with any platform). So the only question left is really between WCF and WebAPI). I don't think the sencha part is any relevant here.